# Uses of various character set configs for MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, character-set

I ran

`SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name LIKE 'character\_set\_%' OR Variable_name LIKE 'collation%';`
and the output is

```
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value             |
+--------------------------+-------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8              |
| character_set_connection | utf8              |
| character_set_database   | latin1            |
| character_set_filesystem | binary            |
| character_set_results    | utf8              |
| character_set_server     | latin1            |
| character_set_system     | utf8              |
| collation_connection     | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database       | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server         | latin1_swedish_ci |
+--------------------------+-------------------+
```

Can someone please explain the exact usage of these settings? My understanding is following:

1. character_set_client: Tells the encoding used by client for query encoding
2. character_set_connection: Encoding used by server to convert query into
3. character_set_database: encoding used for storing data in tables
4. character_set_server: Default encoding if character_set_connection not specified
5. character_set_results: Results are encoded in this format and returned.

Why are there are so many configs required? Couldn't client and server config be kept same always?

I am trying to perform an insert query which fails due to presence of ' in string. Is it recommended to escape it or encode the query? Also, how can I encode it in golang?

Comment: there's a lot of tutorial from net.. you can explore it.

Comment: The error you see has nothing to do with a character set. You probably just have a malformed query.

Comment: It's not an error. I did not find a good documentation on the differences in these configs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you must escape any strings being sent into MySQL.  In particular at least, `'`, `"`, and `\` must be escaped.  Otherwise, do you think will happen when inserting the name `O'Brian` into a table thus?:

```
 INSERT INTO t (name) VALUES ('O'Brian');
```

Quoting and escaping are independent of `character_set%` values.

A column can have any desired `CHARACTER SET`.
A table can have any desired *default* `CHARACTER SET`.
A database can have any desired *default* `CHARACTER SET`.  Note: This setting is useless if you are explicit when `CREATEing` columns or tables.
The server can have any desired *default* `CHARACTER SET`.  Note: This setting is useless if you are explicit when `CREATEing` databases/tables/columns.

Meanwhile, the *client* can have any different `CHARACTER SET`.  But the way to tell the server what encoding the client has is via 3 of those settings (client/connection/results).  The can be set en masse via

```
SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

However, it is usually "better" to establish the client's encoding via some parameter during the connection process.  (The syntax for such varies from client to client -- Java/PHP/VB/etc.)

Why so many?  It is probably too many.  Virtually all practical cases are handled by changing that trio of settings; meanwhile, the other settings can be ignored.

One more thing:  Stored routines have a charset and collation, and I think that comes from the database setting.